# PPM - install module from a given repository

Tags: perl

I am using ActiveState Perl and using PPM for installing modules. I run the ppm commands through batch file. something like

```
ppm rep add Bribes http://www.bribes.org/perl/ppm
ppm rep add UWinnipeg http://theoryx5.uwinnipeg.ca/ppms
ppm rep add Trouchelle http://trouchelle.com/ppm/

ppm install SOAP-Lite
```

So, I am using these three repositories from where I install various modules. 
`SOAP::Lite` module is available on all the three respositories but it seems to be good to use bribes respository to install it. Please refer this link

http://www.mail-archive.com/perl-win32-users@listserv.activestate.com/msg38184.html

During installing SOAP-Lite using ppm install, how can I specify the repository? I understand that we can specify the url, but I am looking something to use the repository name (Bribes, UWinnipeg, Trouchelle). Please let me know if we have any such approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have PPM version > 3. These commands will help you.

`ppm> rep`

to get a list of the repositories you have listed, the active one will be marked with a leading '*'. Then type

`ppm> rep set X`

where X is the number of the repository you want to search.